# Type alias for function arguments in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, refactoring, using, type-alias

I have a function like this:

```
template <typename P1, typename... Ps> constexpr auto pipe(P1 &&proc1,
  Ps &&...procs) -> Cont<Cont<
    Proc<typename RevProc<P1>::ArgType,
      typename RevProc<typename Last<Ps...>::Type>::RetType>>> {
  using T = typename RevProc<P1>::ArgType;
  using U = typename RevProc<P1>::RetType;
  using V = typename RevProc<typename Last<Ps...>::Type>::RetType;
  return [&] (Cont<Proc<T, V>> &&pass) {
    pipe(move(procs)...)([&] (Proc<U, V> &&proc2) {
      pipe(move(proc1), move(proc2))(move(pass));
    });
  };
}
```

As you may find out that the type declaration is duplicated. Is there any chance to give this function a signature like:

```
template <typename P1, typename... Ps> constexpr auto pipe(P1 &&proc1,
  Ps &&...procs) -> Cont<Cont<Proc<T, V>>>
```

and define `T` and `V` at some proper position?

Comment: Can you just switch to C++14?

Comment: Actually I am using C++14. I am a new comer and know nothing.

Comment: Ah, grea, then just delete the trailing return type! If you want to return that actual type (ratner than convert later), put the type conversion into the return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++14, you can just let the type be deduced:

```
template <typename P1, typename... Ps>
constexpr auto pipe(P1 &&proc1, Ps &&...procs) {
  using T = typename RevProc<P1>::ArgType;
  using U = typename RevProc<P1>::RetType;
  using V = typename RevProc<typename Last<Ps...>::Type>::RetType;
  return Cont<Cont<Proc<T, V>>>([&](Cont<Proc<T, V>> &&pass) {
    pipe(std::move(procs)...)([&](Proc<U, V> &&proc2) {
      pipe(std::move(proc1), std::move(proc2))(std::move(pass));
    });
  });
}
```

By the way, some of your uses of `std::move` doesn't look legitimate, since `pipe` may well be called with lvalues that the caller doesn't expect to be moved from. It's better to actually forward what you take by forwarding reference:

```
  return Cont<Cont<Proc<T, V>>>([&](Cont<Proc<T, V>> &&pass) {
    pipe(std::forward<Ps>(procs)...)([&](Proc<U, V> &&proc2) {
      pipe(std::forward<P1>(proc1), std::move(proc2))(std::move(pass));
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. Hard to imagine that I have a such strong compiler who take me a whole day to explain the whole `RevProc` thing to it.

Comment: @Cowsay: Yeah, six years ago was a dark time :-) Now it's all shiny and better.

Comment: Personally, I'd add some `decay` to those perfect forwarded arg types being passed to traits classes